# Finding the center of an aruco marker

Tags: aruco

I have done pose estimation of the marker and obtained the rvec and tvec values. I do not know how to find it's center as I need to draw a cylinder which requires the center value.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

The tvec of a marker is the translation (x,y,z) of the marker from the origin; the distance unit is whatever unit you used to define your printed calibration chart (ie, if you described your calibration chart to OpenCV using mm, then the distance unit in your tvecs is mm).

The rvec of a marker is a 3D rotation vector which defines both an axis of rotation and the rotation angle about that axis, and gives the marker's orientation.

you can get the marker position using tvec

```
x = '{:.2f}'.format(tvec[0])
y = '{:.2f}'.format(tvec[1])
z = '{:.2f}'.format(tvec[2])
```

you can calculate the center pixel of the marker using **corners** which is returned by **aruco.detectMarkers**

```
corners, ids, rejected = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(image=gray_img,dictionary=aruco_dict,parameters=parameters)

x_sum = corners[0][0][0][0]+ corners[0][0][1][0]+ corners[0][0][2][0]+ corners[0][0][3][0]
y_sum = corners[0][0][0][1]+ corners[0][0][1][1]+ corners[0][0][2][1]+ corners[0][0][3][1]
    
x_centerPixel = x_sum*.25
y_centerPixel = y_sum*.25
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did the calibration correctly, tvec values will be the distances in xyz axis' respectively. For example, if you did the calibration correctly and you calibrated in meters, you will get the distances in meters. For further discussion, please upload examples on images with marker and tvecs your program found.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.
Download the images for calibration from [here](https://github.com/njanirudh/Aruco_Tracker/tree/master/calib_images).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cv2.aruco as aruco
import glob
import math

markerLength = 0.25

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

objpoints = [] 
imgpoints = []

images = glob.glob('calib_images/*.jpg')

for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7,6),None)

    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7,6), corners2,ret)


ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)

calibrationFile = "calibrationFileName.xml"
calibrationParams = cv2.FileStorage(calibrationFile, cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ) 
camera_matrix = calibrationParams.getNode("cameraMatrix").mat() 
dist_coeffs = calibrationParams.getNode("distCoeffs").mat() 
count = 1
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_6X6_250)
    arucoParameters =  aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
    aruco_list = {}
    corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, aruco_dict, parameters=arucoParameters)
    if np.all(ids != None):
        if len(corners):
            for k in range(len(corners)):
                temp_1 = corners[k]
                temp_1 = temp_1[0]
                temp_2 = ids[k]
                temp_2 = temp_2[0]
                aruco_list[temp_2] = temp_1
        key_list = aruco_list.keys()
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        for key in key_list:
            dict_entry = aruco_list[key]    
            centre = dict_entry[0] + dict_entry[1] + dict_entry[2] + dict_entry[3]
            centre[:] = [int(x / 4) for x in centre]
            orient_centre = centre + [0.0,5.0]
            centre = tuple(centre)  
            orient_centre = tuple((dict_entry[0]+dict_entry[1])/2)
            cv2.circle(frame,centre,1,(0,0,255),8)
        display = aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame, corners)
        display = np.array(display)
    else:
        display = frame

    cv2.imshow('Display',display)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

the OpenCV function estimatePoseSingleMarkers()

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html#ga84dd2e88f3e8c3255eb78e0f79571bd1

this returns you the rvecs, tvecs, _objPoints. the tvecs is where the center point is, the X,Y,Z coordinates in the same mesure unit that you use on the calibration for the camera matrix.

Make sure the calibration is done correctly.

if you want the center pixel and not the world coordinate, you don't need rvec or tvec. I think this is want  you want to put images on the feed.

use the coners given by the function cv2.aruco.detectMarkers()

corners, ids, rejects = aruco.detectMarkers(image=gray, dictionary=aruco_dic, parameters=paramt)

then for each tag

```
_centerY = int((_corner[0][1] + _corner[2][1]) / 2)
_centerX = int((_corner[0][0] + _corner[2][0]) / 2)
```

hope this helps

Comment: Imagine that aruco marker is captured slant with some angle, in that case, it is not possible to have centre equidistant from marker

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dictionary = cv2.aruco.Dictionary_get(cv2.aruco.DICT_4X4_250)
parameters = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
markerCorners, markerIds, rejectedCandidates = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(gray, dictionary, parameters=parameters)
for corner in markerCorners:
    centerX = (corner[0][0][0] + corner[0][1][0] + corner[0][2][0] + corner[0][3][0]) / 4
    centerY = (corner[0][0][1] + corner[0][1][1] + corner[0][2][1] + corner[0][3][1]) / 4
    center = (int(centerX), int(centerY))
```